# java.util.Pattern API "puzzle"

Tags: java, pattern-matching

Does anybody know where in Pattern API the behaviour of this line of code is described

`System.out.println("000".matches("(0)\\10`"));

I think few people can say what it prints until they run it. API says

```
\n Whatever the n-th capturing group matched
```

It does not say that n must be 1 digit. Is it 10-th or 1-th group in my test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You attempt to match the character `0` between parenthesis, and then you want the previous matched character `\1` to be there also, followed by a `0` character. `000` does verify that pattern and thus the `match()` method returns `true`, so it prints `true`.

Since the matcher did not found `10` capturing groups, it interprets it as the first one `\1` then the character `0`.

A more complex example shows that if the matcher find `N` capturing group > 9 and that the available number of capturing groups is enough, it works also:

```
System.out.println(
    "01234567891011 01120".matches(
        "(0)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)(10)(11) \\1\\12\\30"
    )
);
```

Is true because `0` is in the first capturing group `\1` and `11` is in the capturing group `\12`, finally there is no captured group number `\30` so it is interpreted as back reference `\3` (which is character `2`) then the character `0`.

Comment: For me it is clear, but the documentation could be improved for this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour in this case is described in the section [Comparison to Perl 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/Pattern.html) of the Pattern api:

> In Perl, \1 through \9 are always interpreted as back references; a backslash-escaped number greater than 9 is treated as a back reference if at least that many subexpressions exist, otherwise it is interpreted, if possible, as an octal escape. In this class octal escapes must always begin with a zero. **In this class, \1 through \9 are always interpreted as back references, and a larger number is accepted as a back reference if at least that many subexpressions exist at that point in the regular expression**, otherwise the parser will drop digits until the number is smaller or equal to the existing number of groups or it is one digit.